# C# How to iterate in all TR & TD of multiple html table and extract value

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to parse multiple html table using htmlagility pack. i want to iterate in all TD and extract values.

please have a look at this url https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1108134/000110813423000018/bhlb-20230630.htm

the above url has many tabular data whose html tables i have to parse.

if any one inpect html table code then notice some time **TD** has direct value.
some time **TD** has **SPAN** tag which has value and some time **SPAN** has a custom tag **<ix:nonfraction>** which has value.

I tried this code to iterate in all tr and td but no luck. my objective is to iterate in all html tables and extract values from TD.

This code i tried

```
var table1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        var tbody = table1.ChildNodes["tbody"];
        var lst = new List<Table1>();
        foreach (var row in tbody.ChildNodes.Where(r => r.Name == "tr"))
        {
            var tbl1 = new Table1();
            var columnsArray = row.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.Name == "td").ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    tbl1.Course = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
                if (i == 1)
                    tbl1.Count = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
                if (i == 2)
                    tbl1.Correct = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
            }
            lst.Add(tbl1);
        }
```

Any kind of help or direction would be a great assitance. Thanks